# insert key$ and $value to database form foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data of key and value from foreach. But I am getting error saying- Notice: Array to string conversion in…..(line number 22)
but I have checked both $key and $value using var_dump and found the array values are perfect. Then whats the solution to insert this $key $value data at a time to my database? also please note when i run it, the $key value is inserting successfully in db but $value value field is getting blink and getting same error in browser. you can check my db table in attached picture if required

```
foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $key => $value) {
 mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO combine (rand_id,product_id,product_qty)VALUES('$rand_id','$key','$value')");
}
```

[image]

[image: print_r($_POST['qty']); result]

Comment: sorry? what spaces?

Comment: `print_r($_POST['qty'])` check this first, according to error, `$value` is an array

Comment: btw. consider inserting them with just one INSERT INTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your array and error message `$value` is not a string, its an array, you can get the value from $value by using one more `foreach()`.

**Example:**

```
foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $finalVal) {
    $include[] = "('$rand_id','$key','$finalVal')";
  } 
}
$values = implode(",", $include);

$query = "INSERT INTO combine (rand_id,product_id,product_qty) VALUES $values";
```

Also note that, you can INSERT values in one single query as given example. Store all values in an array and than [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with comma.

*In last, your code is open for SQL Injection, you need to prevent your code. You can follow this post: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)* Yes Prepared Statements & Parameterized Queries is the best option for preventing.

Comment: @KevinHeimlich: glad to help u